# Using variables with UDJC in Pentaho

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

can I somehow make a variable declared in a User Defined Java Class(UDJC) to be usable in another User Defined Java Class? For example I have UDJC1 and UDJC2 in the same transformation and I declare a HashMap(not String, which could be set with SetVariable() function) in UDJC1 and want to use it in UDJC2. Between the two steps there is a blocking step too, so the UDJC1 fills all the needed data in the Map.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `Stream Lookup` before your UDJCs to get the data into your data flow?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variable in one UDJC can not accessible to other UDJC. I think using adding parameter you may be solved your issues. Click Edit->setting->parameter and add your parameter  then open your UDJC and click on parameter tab and set tag and value, in value box you press ctrl+space it shows all defined parameter select your parameter name and access that parameter in your UDJC using getParameter method and set that parameter value and access same as in other UDJC class.